# extending django user model

Tags: django, extending

I am extending the User object in django and have a user profile. So using the post_save hook I save a user profile in the following way:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        userObj, createdUser = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

It works fine when I run the shell, via python manage.py shell; saving a user object and user profile in the tables but if I test by launching a request, in the views.py that handles that request I do the following

```
def handleRequest(request):
    user = User(username="test",email="test",password="test")

    user.save()
```

Of course I created a HttpResponse and returned a response as well but omitted it for brevity. The results are i get a User entry saved in auth_user but no user profile. What the dealy? Please help.

Comment: have you looked at [django-profiles](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles)?

Answer (score 1):

can not access the user profile, because you have in the user profile is a relationship.

you need add fields.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    home_address = models.TextField()
    phone_numer = models.PhoneNumberField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

for more information check the following link

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/

Comment: yea i've looked at that lin before and it would not work consistently. I will investigate and try it again..I've seen numerous links online on how to extend the user model...but have had problems with all of them. In the meantime I am no longer using the post_save hook and just creating the user profile object manually in the request handler method in the view file. Thanks for the link.